# Matching individual elements of strings

Tags: c++, string, match

I would like to know if there is an easy and efficient way of matching the individual string elements. I am trying to match two string and check the matching elements from the start. If the first elements fail to match, then i would say there is no match. I have written some code to make it work, but i am not sure if there is an easy way to do this in C++.

**Example program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<char> matches; 
  std::string str1 = "ABCDE";
  std::string str2 = "ABCED";

  for(int i =0; i< str1.size() ; i++)
  {

    if(str1.at(i) == str2.at(i))
    {
       std::cout<<"match found"<<std::endl;
      matches.push_back(str1.at(i));

    }

       else
       std::cout<<"match not found"<<std::endl;
  }

}
```

You can [test the example program here](http://cpp.sh/4qo5i). Is there any efficient way to match the individual string elements.

Comment: What is the measure of efficiency? Per the problem, the `char`s at the same positions of the two `string`s can be compared until one of the string ends. This is `O(min(N1, N2))` and reasonable. (BTW, in current code, `str2.at(i)` may throw if `str2` is shorter than `str1`.)

Comment: What are you trying to do?
if you just trying to compare string, use compare function that is in string library. 
ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: Is there a specific need, or just some testing ? If there is a specific need please indicate it.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for your comments. Are you sure of throwing the error if `str2` is shorter than `str1`. In the example it no so.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis I want to check how many character of `str1` match with `str2` from the start.